How to convert predicted bounding boxes from YOLOv8 to shapefiles
I have adopted the YOLOv8 model to detect cars from an orthophoto. My goal is to convert the predicted bounding boxes to shapefiles so I can view the output in a GIS environment. I have tried several approaches, but the result I got was not what I expected. The shapefiles appear clustered in a location that is completely outside the extent of the orthophoto. How do I resolve this?
Attached is the code used:
    # Commented out IPython magic to ensure Python compatibility.
    # %%capture
    # !pip install supervision ultralytics rasterio
    # !pip installfiona  rtree shapely
    # !pip install geopandas
    
    # Imports
    # Library for managing files and file structures
    import os
    import yaml
    import time
    import shutil
    from google.colab import files
    
    
    # Library for sending HTTPS requests
    import requests
    
    # Libraries for manipulating raster data
    from PIL import Image
    import rasterio as rio
    from rasterio.plot import reshape_as_image
    
    # Scipy ecosystem libraries for numerical computing and data visualization
    import random
    import numpy as np
    import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
    
    # Libraries for handling geospadata data
    import shapely.geometry
    import geopandas as gpd
    from shapely.geometry import Polygon
    
    # Libraries for implementing computer vision tasks
    import cv2
    import torch
    import supervision as sv
    from ultralytics import YOLO
    
    # Create list of folders and subfolders for file storage
    folderList = [
        "raw_inputs",
        "images/train",
        "images/test",
        "labels/train",
        "labels/test",
        "sub_images",
    ]
    
    for folder in folderList:
      os.makedirs(folder, exist_ok = True)
    
    """### Input image
    Available at <a href="https://map.openaerialmap.org/">OpenAerial.org</a>
    """
    
    # Set up image url
    img_url = "https://oin-hotosm.s3.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/668f53ce1684770001c338e3/0/668f53ce1684770001c338e4.tif"
    
    # Set up destination folder
    dest_dir = "/content/raw_inputs"
    
    # Prepare destination path
    dest_path = os.path.join(dest_dir, "orthophoto.tif")
    
    # Download the image
    response = requests.get(img_url)
    with open(dest_path, "wb") as destFile:
      destFile.write(response.content)
    
    print(f"Image downloaded image to {dest_path}")
    
    """###  Converting GeoTIFF to JPG"""
    
    # Access the raster data
    with rio.open(dest_path) as srcFile:
      # Get affine transform for georeferencing
      transform = srcFile.transform
      # Get coordinate reference system
      crs = srcFile.crs
      # Read the Red band
      red = srcFile.read(1)
      # Read the Green band
      green = srcFile.read(2)
      # Read the Red band
      blue = srcFile.read(3)
    
      # Merge the bands
      compositeRGB = np.dstack((red, green, blue))
    
      # Display the composite image
      plt.imshow(compositeRGB)
      # Turn off the axes
      plt.axis("off")
      # Expand the margin
      plt.margins(0, 0)
      plt.gca().xaxis.set_major_locator(plt.NullLocator())
      plt.gca().yaxis.set_major_locator(plt.NullLocator())
    
      # Set the output jpg resolution
      dpi = 3000
      # Save the image as jpeg
      plt.savefig(os.path.join(dest_dir, "orthophoto.jpg"),
               dpi = dpi,
               bbox_inches = "tight",
               pad_inches = 0)
    
    """### Split the Image to Sub-images"""
    
    # Get the image
    img = Image.open(os.path.join(dest_dir, "orthophoto.jpg"))
    
    # Specify the number of segments to use in splitting the image
    num_segments = 15
    
    # Get the image dimensions
    width, height = img.size
    
    # Divide the image per the number of segments
    sub_width = width // num_segments
    sub_height = height // num_segments
    
    # Loop through each sub-image and save it
    for i in range(num_segments):
      for j in range(num_segments):
        # Compute the new dimensions
        top = i * sub_height
        bottom = top + sub_height
        left = j * sub_width
        right = left + sub_width
        # Crop the image using the new dimensions
        sub_img = img.crop((left, top, right, bottom))
    
        # Save the images
        sub_img.save(f"/content/sub_images/sub_image_{i}_{j}.jpg")
    
    # Compress the sub-images folder
    folderName = "sub_images"
    shutil.make_archive(folderName, "zip", folderName)
    
    # Download the compressed folder
    files.download(f"{folderName}.zip")
    
    """### Prepare Training and Testing Databases"""
    
    # Define a helper function to split the images and their labels into train and test sets
    def splitIMG(source_dir, labels_train_dir, labels_test_dir, images_train_dir, images_test_dir, train_ratio = 0.75):
      # List all .txt files starting with sub_image_
      txt_files = [f for f in os.listdir(source_dir) if f.startswith("sub_image_") and f.endswith(".txt")]
    
      # Shuffle the list
      random.shuffle(txt_files)
    
      # Set the splitting ratio
      split_index = int(len(txt_files) * train_ratio)
    
      # Split into train and test sets
      train_files = txt_files[:split_index]
      test_files = txt_files[split_index:]
    
      # Loop through the files and move each to its corresponding destination folder
      for text_file in train_files:
        shutil.move(os.path.join(source_dir, text_file), os.path.join(labels_train_dir, text_file))
    
        # Replace .txt with .jpg
        jpg_file = text_file.replace(".txt", ".jpg")
        if os.path.exists(os.path.join(source_folder_image, jpg_file)):
          shutil.copy(os.path.join(source_folder_image, jpg_file), os.path.join(images_train_dir, jpg_file))
    
        # Repeat for the test sets
      for text_file in test_files:
        shutil.move(os.path.join(source_dir, text_file), os.path.join(labels_test_dir, text_file))
        # Replace .txt with .jpg
        jpg_file = text_file.replace(".txt", ".jpg")
        if os.path.exists(os.path.join(source_folder_image, jpg_file)):
          shutil.copy(os.path.join(source_folder_image, jpg_file), os.path.join(images_test_dir, jpg_file))
    
    # Apply the function
    source_dir = "/content/raw_inputs/"
    images_train_dir = "/content/images/train/"
    images_test_dir = "/content/images/test/"
    labels_train_dir = "/content/labels/train/"
    labels_test_dir = "/content/labels/test/"
    source_folder_image = "/content/sub_images/"
    
    splitIMG(source_dir, labels_train_dir, labels_test_dir, images_train_dir, images_test_dir, train_ratio = 0.75)
    print("Files moved successfully")
    
    """### Train YOLOv8
    The next step is to create the config file for the YOLO algorithm and train the model based on the sub-images and their labels in the train and test directories
    """
    
    # Create a config file for YOLO
    data = {
        'train': "/content/images/train",
        'val': "/content/images/test",
        'nc': 1,
        'names': ['car']
    }
    
    # Write the yolo config file
    with open("yolo_config.yaml", 'w') as yolo_file:
      yaml.dump(data, yolo_file)
    
    # Specify the yolo file
    yolo_file = "yolo_config.yaml"
    
    # Create a YOLO model
    model = YOLO("yolov8m.yaml").load("yolov8m.pt")
    
    # Train the model
    model.train(data = f"{yolo_file}",
                epochs = 30)
    
    """### Deploy YOLOv8 on the Entire Image"""
    
    # Load the trained weights
    model = YOLO("runs/detect/train/weights/best.pt")
    
    # Run predictions
    img_path = 'sub_images/'
    
    results = model.predict(source = img_path, save = True, conf = 0.9)
    
    # Get the count of cars in the image
    total_cars = 0
    
    # Iterate over the results to count the number of cars detected
    for item in results:
      # Count the number of detections
      total_cars += len(item.boxes)
    print(f"Total number of cars detected: {total_cars}")
    
    # Write the number to a text file
    with open("number_of_cars.txt", 'w') as car_count:
      car_count.write(f"Total number of cars detected: {total_cars}\n")
    
    """### Putting all together"""
    
    # Create a new image with the size of the sub-images
    sub_image_size = Image.open("runs/detect/predict/sub_image_13_6.jpg").size
    image_with = sub_image_size[0] * num_segments
    image_height = sub_image_size[1] * num_segments
    
    # Create a new image with the size of the sub-images
    new_image = Image.new("RGB", (image_with, image_height))
    
    # Loop through the sub images and merge them
    for i in range(num_segments):
      for j in range(num_segments):
        sub_image = Image.open(f"runs/detect/predict/sub_image_{i}_{j}.jpg")
        x = j * sub_image_size[0]
        y = i * sub_image_size[1]
        new_image.paste(sub_image, (x, y))
    
    # Save the new image
    new_image.save("combinedNewImage.jpg")
    
    print(results)
    
    """### Converting the bounding boxes to shapefiles"""
    
    # Function to convert pixel coordinates to geographic coordinates
def pixel_to_geo(x, y, transform):
    return rio.transform.xy(transform, y, x)

# Create an empty list to store the geometries and class labels
geometries = []
class_labels = []
classNames = ['car']

for r in results:
    boxes = r.boxes
    for box in boxes:
        x1, y1, x2, y2 = box.xyxy[0]
        x1, y1, x2, y2 = int(x1), int(y1), int(x2), int(y2)
        
        # Convert pixel coordinates to geographic coordinates
        x1_geo, y1_geo = pixel_to_geo(x1, y1, transform)
        x2_geo, y2_geo = pixel_to_geo(x2, y2, transform)
        
        # Create a box in geographic coordinates
        geo_box = shapely.geometry.box(x1_geo, y1_geo, x2_geo, y2_geo)
        geometries.append(geo_box)


        class_label = classNames[int(box.cls[0])]
        class_labels.append(class_label)

# Create a GeoDataFrame from the list of geometries and class labels
gdf = gpd.GeoDataFrame({'geometry': geometries, 'class_label': class_labels}, crs = crs)

# Save the GeoDataFrame to a shapefile
output_shapefile = 'bboxes.shp'
gdf.to_file(output_shapefile, driver='ESRI Shapefile')



Please never just say "but I have been unsuccessful" that's the same as but it didn't work and will attract downvotes and close votes.  Instead can you edit your question and say what actually did happen. Was there an application/software crash, was there an error message (if so what was the complete error message as text, not screenshot), did the program run but produce incorrect/unexpected results (if so what were they)?

maybe your image have lost its projection information when converting from geotiff to jpg
